# Running 2 PeriodicWorkRequest simultaneously

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

Is it possible to enque two periodic work requests simultaneously using the work manager.
I'm trying something like

```
val workRequest1: WorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<work1>(15, MINUTES).build()
val workRequest2: WorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<work2>(15, MINUTES).build()

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(listOf(workRequest1, workRequest2))
```

Comment: If you don't want to chain tasks and executed them independently, then above code should work as expected according to the doc of enqueue method. But did you encounter any error after executing the above code?

Comment: Nope, One of the worker is not running, I think it may have something to do with the worker (I'm using a ListenableWorker), but both of them are coded in the same way (the start methods). I'm thinking of posting the code after some time

Comment: Update: I didn't encounter any error, both of the workers are running fine, but one of the worker fails to perform a firestore operation.  btw, I'm using a listenable worker.